# selenium - drop down - python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
<input id="clusteredDownloadButton" name="clusteredDownloadButton" type="submit" value="Download" onclick="submitForm('download',1,{source:'clusteredDownloadButton'});return false;" class="submit">
```

**the xpath:** //*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]

```
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="0">PSI-MITAB 2.5</option>
```

**the xpath:** //*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]/option[2]

so i need to select the PSI-MITLAB 2.5 option and the download this type of document

```
<input id="clusteredDownloadButton" name="clusteredDownloadButton" type="submit" value="Download" onclick="submitForm('download',1,{source:'clusteredDownloadButton'});return false;" class="submit">
```

**the xpath:** //*[@id="clusteredDownloadButton"]

I tried a lot of things from whatever I found online, it keeps giving me an error. Please help!

attempted code:

code#1

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]').click()
driver.select_by_visible_text("PSI-MITAB 2.5")
```

code#2

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]/option[2]').click()
```

code#3

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]')
dropdown.select_by_value('PSI-MITAB 2.5')
```

code#4

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]/option[2]')
dropdown.select_by_value('PSI-MITAB 2.5')
```

all of them keep throwing an error!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Comment: time.sleep(5)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]/option[2]')
dropdown.select_by_value('PSI-MITAB 2.5')




time.sleep(5)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]')
dropdown.select_by_value('PSI-MITAB 2.5')

Comment: #d_type = "downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"
#d_element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda driver:driver.find_element_by_id(d_type))
#Select(d_element).select_by_visible_text("PSI-MITAB 2.5")
#time.sleep(5)

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='downloadClusterSelectOneChoice']/option[@value='0']").click()
#wait to process
#time.sleep(5)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]').click()
#driver.select_by_visible_text("PSI-MITAB 2.5")


all of them give me and error :(

Comment: Please add the code into the question instead of comments so that it's easier for everyone to find and it can be formatted properly and more easily read. Thanks.

Comment: thank you sir. I added the code. please check :)

Comment: I formatted the code as code. What errors are the different lines throwing?

Comment: Thank you @JeffC

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"downloadClusterSelectOneChoice\"]"}

all of them have the same error, i just pasted the code for one of them.

Comment: Something is wrong with your XPath. Have you tried something simple like `driver.find_element_by_id("downloadClusterSelectOneChoice")`? You really don't need an XPath to find an element by ID.

Comment: Yes i did. It's not working. I have no idea why.Tried so many options now trying to look for another way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`select_by_value`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_value) or [`select_by_index`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_index).

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath(dropdown_xpath)
dropdown.select_by_value('PSI-MITAB 2.5')
```

Comment: time.sleep(5)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]/option[2]')
dropdown.select_by_value('PSI-MITAB 2.5')




time.sleep(5)
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="downloadClusterSelectOneChoice"]')
dropdown.select_by_value('PSI-MITAB 2.5')

both of them give me and error :(

Comment: What's the error? Looks like you're not getting/finding the element successfully, rather than the issue of selecting the right value in the 2nd step. Try debugging a bit with `dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath(dropdown_xpath)` and then `print dropdown.get_attribute('innerHTML')`. If you haven't found the element, that print/innerHTML line will fail anyway.